# Spring mvc not showing correct http status

Tags: http, spring-mvc, servlets, model-view-controller, httpwebresponse

In my `controller` class, I check if ID is correct, if not, the controller should throw an exception:

```
        if (!ID.matches("blablabla")) {
        throw new InvalidIDException();
    }
```

Then in my exception class, I add an annotation

```
@ResponseStatus(value= HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,reason="Invalid ID")
public class InvalidIDException extends RuntimeException{
public InvalidIDException(){}

public InvalidIDException(String message) {super(message);}
public InvalidIDException(Throwable cause) {super(cause);}
}
```

So if ID is invalid, it should throw a http 400 error.(I look at the error by right clicking on the `webpage` and `inspect element`, then `network`) However, I am not sure why it still shows http 404 if ID is invalid.

Updated:
It seems that if I add one line of code inside throw exception, it works.  :

```
if (!ID.matches("blablabla")) {
response.sendError(400,"invalid id");
        throw new InvalidIDException();
    }
```

Comment: Do you get a `404` for both a valid and an invalid ID ? If so, most likely your request does not get handled by this controller (because of some `@RequestMapping` or perhaps `servlet-mapping` issue).

Comment: @CostiCiudatu I got 200 for correct ID. The controller handles my request perfectly except, if order is invalid, it still shows 404 instead of 400.

Comment: What does your @RequestMapping look like ? Can you set a breakpoint and see what happens after the exception gets thrown ?

Comment: @CostiCiudatu @RequestMapping(value ="/tt/{ID}/{ImageDimension}", method = RequestMethod.GET)

Comment: @CostiCiudatu I found out a possible solution. Before I call throw new InvalidIDException(). I add one line of code :             response.sendError(400,"invalid id"). It seems it works.